# Are there Windows Phone Apps that can tell me which apps are consuming how many % of battery juice

Tags: battery

Are there Windows Phone Apps that can tell me which Windows Phone Apps are consuming how much of battery? and able to tell me how many % left for the phone before it become battery flat?

Comment: Native now in windows phone 8.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me answer your questions separately:

1) No app can monitor the activity of another app (because Windows Phone apps are completely sandboxed).  That includes battery usage.

2) There are apps available for WP8 that can tell you how much battery is left. You ca find a list here:

http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store/search?q=battery%20status

Comment: Cannot one app find out what other apps are running? If so, it would be possible to write an app to estimate the battery usage of each app using an intelligent statistical procedure.

Comment: A third party app does not have the ability to know what else is running at that moment. Remember, only one app can run in the foreground at a time. Apps can run in the background periodically on a schedule that is devised by the OS or if they are a VOIP app and currently in a call (there is also the resource-intensive background task but that only runs when plugged in, so doesn't really apply here).  Either way, you still have no insight into what else is going on with the OS.